# How to Synchronize Azure Ad Users for Authorization

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, authorization

Microsoft has plenty of documentation on how to handle authentication (authN) with Microsoft identity platform but only little information about proper authorization (authZ). As of right now, I have a single-page application (SPA), that uses MSAL to login users. We also have a backend that validates access tokens sent from the frontend. With this in place, authN works as expected.

For authZ, I have `User`, `Permission` and `UserPermission` tables in the backend which populate users with permissions. I have a custom middleware that queries the database for user and permissions and attaches the permissions as claims to the `ClaimsIdentity` to the `ClaimsPrincipal`.

**What is the best way to get the Azure AD users into the backend database?**

In the frontend I need to display a list of all users which can then be populated with permissions. However, I don't know the best way to "sync" these users such that they can be displayed and populated with data in my backend database.

Current architecture:

[image]

Note: I am aware that the Microsoft Identity Platform provides an RBAC mechanism which adds a role claim to the access token. However, my authorization is far more complex such that I cannot use it and secondly authZ claims should not be part of a JWT.

Comment: The normal flow is to use MS Graph to import each user during authentication but you can easily use the same API to bulk migrate or _reflect_ large groups of users. You also do not have to use JWT for your claims and security roles, you just need some middleware to inject the claims from your backend into the user's Identity after or as part of the AD auth flow. There isn't really a "best" way, you just need to explore the simplest way for your scenario. Maybe follow intro posts on local security or Identity Server first, then add AD as an external auth flow to that.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That’s actually exaclt the flow that I thought of. In regards to your last sentence, I kind of want avoid building my own auth. and then adding AD as external because then I am reinventing the wheel and I won’t be as good doing auth. as Microsoft and all other IDPs.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD supports SCIM 2.0. It provides support to sync users and groups in a standarized way to any backend, which implement the required SCIM endpoints.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/users-groups/scim/aad

There are plenty of paid and open-source packages for .NET implementing the backend part: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Scim&frameworks=&tfms=&packagetype=&prerel=true&sortby=relevance